# Filtering max from array and flattening document

Tags: c#, mongodb, mapreduce, aggregation-framework

I am new to the mongo and my document looks something like bellow

```
{
  Abc : [
   { _id : 1 , val : "somevalue" },
   { _id : 2 , val : "new value" },
   { _id : 3 , val : "new new value" }
  ],
  Xyz : [
    { _id : 1 , val : 3456},
    { _id : 2 , val : 7689 },
    { _id : 3 , val : 21342}
  ],
  Ghi : [
    { _id : 1 , val : "somevalue" },
    { _id : 2 , val : "new value" },
    { _id : 3 , val : "new new value" }
  ],
}
```

each field value should filtered by max _id, 
i.e. Abc : “new new value”

resulting output should look like

```
{
  _id : 1
  Abc : "new new value",
  Xyz : 21342,
  Ghi : "new new value"
}
```

Note: fields may vary or might not present in db

Comment: By "fields may vary or might not present" do you mean the field Abc/Xyc/Ghi, or do you mean they might be empty array?

Comment: Hi Yaoxing, 
yes, by fields I mean ABC/Xyz/Ghi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were looking at standard projection with `.find()` then there really isn't much of an option there for "sorting" or "flattening" the array members, but it is your fastest option if the elements are already in order:

```js
db.test.find({},{ 
    "Abc": { "$slice": -1 },
    "Ghi": { "$slice": -1 },
    "Xyz": { "$slice": -1 }
})
```

With it's output:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("537d876dbeeccb8f75e1ef9a"),
    "Abc" : [{ "_id" : 3, "val" : "new new value" }],
    "Xyz" : [{ "_id" : 3, "val" : 21342 }],
    "Ghi" : [{ "_id" : 3, "val" : "new new value" }]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("537d87fe348f6339113e85ae"),
    "Abc" : [{ "_id" : 3, "val" : "new new value" }],
    "Ghi" : [{ "_id" : 3, "val" : "new new value" }]
}
```

You could possibly do something like this with the aggregation framework if you are prepared to nominate all of your possible fields:

```js
db.test.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
        "Abc": { "$ifNull": [ "$Abc", [ false ] ] },
        "Ghi": { "$ifNull": [ "$Ghi", [ false ] ] },
        "Xyz": { "$ifNull": [ "$Xyz", [ false ] ] }
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$Abc" },
    { "$unwind": "$Ghi" },
    { "$unwind": "$Xyz" },
    { "$sort": { "Abc._id": -1, "Ghi._id": -1, "Xyz": -1 } },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "Abc": { "$first": "$Abc.val" },
        "Ghi": { "$first": "$Ghi.val" },
        "Xyz": { "$first": "$Xyz.val" }
    }}
])
```

Which essentially puts a `[ false ]` array in there if the the field does not exist using the [**`$ifNull`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/) operator to stop the later [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) statements from blowing up. Mileage may vary as to whether this is a solution for you. It's output:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("537d876dbeeccb8f75e1ef9a"),
    "Abc" : "new new value",
    "Ghi" : "new new value",
    "Xyz" : 21342
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("537d87fe348f6339113e85ae"),
    "Abc" : "new new value",
    "Ghi" : "new new value",
    "Xyz" : null
}
```

Alternately you can do something more complex with mapReduce, even if there is no actual reducing being done:

```js
db.test.mapReduce(
    function () {

      for ( var k in this ) {
        if ( k === '_id' )
          continue;

        this[k].sort(function(a, b) {
          if ( a._id < b._id ) {
            return -1;
          } else if ( a._id > b._id ) {
            return 1;
          }
          return 0;
        });

        this[k] = this[k].slice(-1)[0].val;

      }

      var id = this._id;
      delete this["_id"];

      emit( id, this );

    },
    function(){},
    {
        "out": { "inline": 1 }
    }
)
```

Which has horrible mapReduce output, but at least you can be flexible with the "keys" you have in the document:

```js
    "results" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("537d876dbeeccb8f75e1ef9a"),
            "value" : {
                "Abc" : "new new value",
                "Xyz" : 21342,
                "Ghi" : "new new value"
            }
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("537d87fe348f6339113e85ae"),
            "value" : {
                "Abc" : "new new value",
                "Ghi" : "new new value"
            }
        }
    ]
```

So that's a few approaches to consider with their individual strengths and weaknesses, but a way to get the job done.

Comment: Thank you so much :) I really liked the map reduce approach, I was just wondering if there is any way to have these properties "abc", "xyz" in actual document and not in value. 
once again thank you so much